Failing to deserialize a tx from rpc, Error deserializing transaction: Reached end of buffer unexpectedly
Hey guys I'm just trying to deserialize a tx from an rpc.
const subscriptionMessage = JSON.stringify({
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        id: 1,
        method: "blockSubscribe",
        params: [
            { mentionsAccountOrProgram: PROGRAM.toBase58() },
            {
                commitment: "confirmed",
                encoding: "base64",
                showRewards: false,
                transactionDetails: "full",
                maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0
            }
        ]
    });
    websocket.send(subscriptionMessage);
    console.log(`Subscribed to blocks mentioning program: ${PROGRAM.toBase58()}`);

    websocket.on('message', (message) => {
        lastMessageTime = Date.now();
        const data = JSON.parse(message);

        if (data.method === 'blockNotification' && data.params && data.params.result) {
            const blockData = data.params.result;
            if (blockData.value && blockData.value.block) {
                const block = blockData.value.block;
                if (block.transactions) {
                    for (const tx of block.transactions) {
                        if (tx.transaction) {
                            try {
                                console.log(tx.transaction[0], "tx");
                                const base64String = tx.transaction[0];
                                const txDataDecoded = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
                                const message = VersionedMessage.deserialize(txDataDecoded);
                                const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(message);

                                break;

tx content before the script :

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

I'm getting this error
Error deserializing transaction: Reached end of buffer unexpectedly
Cannot find a lot of docs either on this topic if you have some tips ! thankssss

The base64 transaction looks ok in the Explorer inspector
I think the issue is that you have a serialized transaction, not transaction message. A transaction is a compiled message + signatures.
Try using const transaction = VersionedTransaction.deserialize(txDataDecoded);
